# I want to see the incoming call on the landline

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

I am working on a react native application and I want to display the number of the incoming call to another phone in the application I wrote on my own phone. What steps should I take?

In my research, it says that it can be integrated with VoIP, but I do not have any information on the subject.

Comment: Contact your VoIP provider and ask them if they have an API to allow you to spy on calls on their network, that would allow you to know when calls are made to particular phone numbers.